# NavigationService remove complete back navigation

Tags: windows-phone-8

Using `NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()` I can remove one entry from the navigation stack. Is there a convenient way to remove *all* back navigation items in my app (scenario: I have a sign-up procedure which consists of multiple pages, and after successful registration I do not want the user to navigate back to the registration steps).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not that inconvenient to do that with `RemoveBackEntry`:

```
while(NavigationService.CanGoBack)
{
    NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use this, a single line code

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null) ;
    }
```